# how to remove text from cell when click on the text of cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

hi i have problem when i am displaying the records of table by clicking on load more cell . problem is this when i click on load more cell  then table must load two more records and then load more text must move forward for example first time 2 records load on table at the 3rd cell is the load more cell when i click on this cell then two more records must load into table and this load more text move to 5th cell . but in my case the problem is when i click on load more cell at 3rd position it also move to fifth position but on 3rd cell record not load and also load more text appear on 3rd cell. kindly tell me how i can handle this problem this is the code

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "XMLAppDelegate.h"
#import "song.h"
#import "BookDetailViewController.h"
@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize mylabel,mylabel1,mylabel2,spinner,cell;
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if([myarray count]>pageSize)
    {
        return pageSize+1;
    }
    return  myarray.count;

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 75;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        song *asong = [appDelegate.artists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]]];

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if(indexPath.row<pageSize)
        {    
            UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 60, 60)];
            imageView.image=image;
            [cell addSubview:imageView];

            CGRect CellFrame1 = CGRectMake(65, 10, 220, 45);
            mylabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame1];
            mylabel1.text = asong.title;

            mylabel1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            mylabel1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel1];
            CGRect CellFrame2 = CGRectMake(65, 47, 150, 25);
            mylabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame2];
            mylabel2.text = asong.artist;

            mylabel2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel2];




            CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(255, 3, 60, 7);
            mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame];
            mylabel.text = asong.duration;
            mylabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            mylabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel];
        }
        else 
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"load more";

            spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];


            cell.accessoryView = spinner;

            [spinner startAnimating];
            [spinner performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];        [spinner release];

        }
    }






    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        return cell;
}   


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

    if (indexPath.row==pageSize) 
    {

        pageSize=pageSize+2;
        [cell reloadInputViews];
        [tableView reloadData];

    }

    /* else if(bdvController == nil)
        bdvController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    song *asong = [appDelegate.artists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    bdvController.aartist = asong;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdvController animated:YES];*/
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pageSize =2;
    // Uncomment the following line to add the Edit button to the navigation bar.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/eminem.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/mj.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/rihanna.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/arrehman.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/alexi_murdoch.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/dido.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/enrique.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/ennio.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/backstreet_boys.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/eminem.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/mj.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/rihanna.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/arrehman.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/alexi_murdoch.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/dido.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/enrique.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/ennio.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/backstreet_boys.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/eminem.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/mj.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/rihanna.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/arrehman.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/alexi_murdoch.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/dido.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/enrique.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/ennio.png",@"http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/backstreet_boys.png", nil];
    appDelegate = (XMLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    self.title = @"Songs";
}



/*
// Override to support editing the list
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
    }   
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the list
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the list
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the list
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
}
*/

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [bdvController release];
    [appDelegate release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: if(indexPath.row<pageSize) cell.textLabel.text = @"";

Comment: lol  i am not initializing the cell with constant string i added subview in cell, lol

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're only configuring a cell if it's nil.  In your example, you will want to replace cell 3's content with some song even when it's not nil.

When deque returns nil, create a new cell and add subviews but **always** update the content based on the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row<pageSize) {
        song *asong = [appDelegate.artists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 60, 60)];
            imageView.tag = 1;
            [cell addSubview:imageView];

            CGRect CellFrame1 = CGRectMake(65, 10, 220, 45);
            mylabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame1];
            mylabel1.tag = 2;

            mylabel1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
            mylabel1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel1];
            CGRect CellFrame2 = CGRectMake(65, 47, 150, 25);
            mylabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame2];
            mylabel2.tag = 2;

            mylabel2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel2];

            CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(255, 3, 60, 7);
            mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame];
            mylabel.tag = 2;
            mylabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            mylabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel];
        }
        UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *mylabel1 = [cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *mylabel2 = [cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *mylabel = [cell viewWithTag:1];


        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]]];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            });
        });


        mylabel1.text = asong.title;
        mylabel2.text = asong.artist;
        mylabel.text = asong.duration;


        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        return cell;
    }
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellloadmore";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.textLabel.text = @"load more";

        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

        cell.accessoryView = spinner;

        [spinner startAnimating];
        [spinner performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];        [spinner release];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: problem is still there when i click on load more button image not load on load more and when i drag table vertically then images wrong images shown on wrong place kindly solve this problem